# Movies inside my application do not load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I had movies outside my app the workded fine. And I used to load them with:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/../Movies/" + mov, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
```

But now I have added the movies to my project because I wish export single EXE at the end. So I added them here:

[image]

And now I use:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Shamir Temp;component/Videos/" + mov);
```

But it not seems to work! Any one maybe knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot play media from resource file, you have to make it as a content and copy always to output directory.

Quote under Remarks section of [**MediaElementClass**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When distributing media with your application, you cannot use a media
>   file as a project resource. In your project file, you must instead set
>   the media type to Content and set CopyToOutputDirectory to
>   PreserveNewest or Always.

Answer (score 1):

When distributing media with your application, you cannot use a media file as a `Project Resource`, this can be done for the `Image` files.

In your project file, you must instead set the resource type to `Content` and set `CopyToOutputDirectory` to *`PreserveNewest`* or *`Always`*.

For more information, please see this link:

[`MSDN: MediaElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx)